# normalized subgroup by another subgroup

Tags: group-theory, definition

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subgroups of the same group $G$. What does it mean for the subgroup $A$ to be normalized by the subgroup $B$?

Comment: It means that $A \lhd \langle A,B \rangle$ is one way to say it.

Comment: Similarly it is sometimes said that $B$ _centralizes_ $A$ in $G$ (or $A$ is _centralized_ by $B$ in $G$) if $B \le C_G(A)$, that is, $B$ is a subgroup of the centralizer of $A$ in $G$. See also a [manual](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jean.michel/gap3/htm/chap007.htm) of a software where these terms are used and defined explicitly in a slightly more general setting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means that for every $b\in B$, $A^b = \{b^{-1}ab\mid a\in A\} = A$. That is, that $B$ is a subgroup of the normalizer of $A$ in $G$.

Comment: could you please explain this statement: "If we want $AB=\{ab|a\in A, b\in B\}$ to be a subgroup of $G$, then we must have $A$ is normalized by $B$".

Comment: @palio: The statement is false; what is true is that if $A$ and $B$ are subgroups, then $AB$ is a subgroup if and only if $AB=\{ab\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$ is equal, as a set, to $BA=\{ba\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$. *If* $B$ normalizes $A$, then this is true: given $a\in A$, $b\in B$, then $ab = b(b^{-1}ab) = ba'\in BA$, so $AB\subseteq BA$, and $ba = bab^{-1}b = a''b\in AB $, so $BA\subseteq AB$. However, it is possible to have $AB=BA$ *without* having $B$ normalize $A$, so it is false that "we **must** have $A$ normalized by $B$". E.g., $G=S_3$, $A=\langle(1,2)\rangle, $B=\langle(1,2,3)\rangle$.

Comment: @palio: In my previous example, $A$ normalizes $B$, of course; but it is also possible to have $AB=BA$ and yet have neither $A$ normalize $B$, nor $B$ normalize $A$. The statement is simply false.