# meaning of a subgroup normalizes .

Tags: group-theory

I know that if a subgroup A is normal subgroup of the subgroup B,then B is contained in the normalizer of A . But I don not know what is the meaning of A normalizes B ?

Comment: repost of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54484/normalized-subgroup-by-another-subgroup

Answer (score 1):

It means that $a^{-1}Ba=B$ for all $a \in A$.