# Meaning of $H$ normalizing $N$.

Tags: group-theory, terminology

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ and $N$ be subgroups of $G$. I wonder what the canonical meaning of "$H$ normalizes $N$" in literature is:

(1) $\forall h\in H$, $h N h^{-1}=N$.

(2) $H=\{h\in G: hNh^{-1}=N\}$, namely $H$ is the normalization of $N$.

I wonder which of the two "definitions" above is more standard in the math literature.

Comment: I feel like I've seen both, and I'd likely use (1), but I'm no expert.

Comment: Here you go: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54484/normalized-subgroup-by-another-subgroup

Comment: It should be (1). (2) states that $H$ is the *normalizer* of $N$, which is a different (but closely related) notion.